# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteracable - Can't reach element

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have no idea why my code doesn't see secound input. When add text to first input successfully receive `OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteracable: Element input.k-formatted-value.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.k-input is not reachable by keyboard` error.

```
By inputOneSrc = By.CssSelector("input.invalid");
By inputTwoSrc = By.CssSelector("input.k-formatted-value.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.k-input");

IWebElement inputFirst = driver.findElement(inputOneSrc);
IWebElement inputSecound = driver.findElement(inputTwoSrc);

inputFirst.SendKeys("abc");
inputSecound.SendKeys("cba");
```

I have tried to use *Clear()* after sending text to *inputFirst* but still couldn't add text to secound input. I think this text is hidden somehow because i can see it using:

```
inputFirst.GetAttribute("value");
inputSecound.GetAttribute("value");
```

But can't just use Text(). Do you know how to resolve it to see text in input?

```
<input type="text" class="k-formatted-value ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid k-input" title="" tabindex="0" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="-999999999999999" aria-valuemax="999999999999999" aria-title="" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: inline-block;">
<input next-focus="" kendo-numeric-text-box="c.numeric" k-options="numericOptions" ng-model="c.Value" style="display: none;" ng-class="{'flow-required': !c.AllowEmpty}" required="" class="ng-pristine k-input ng-invalid ng-invalid-required flow-required invalid ng-touched" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" type="text" aria-valuemin="-999999999999999" aria-valuemax="999999999999999" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">

<input type="text" class="k-formatted-value ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid k-input" title="" tabindex="0" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="-999999999999999" aria-valuemax="999999999999999" aria-title="" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: inline-block;">
<input next-focus="" kendo-numeric-text-box="c.numeric" k-options="numericOptions" ng-model="c.Value" style="display: none;" ng-class="{'flow-required': !c.AllowEmpty}" required="" class="ng-pristine k-input ng-invalid ng-invalid-required flow-required invalid ng-touched" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" type="text" aria-valuemin="-999999999999999" aria-valuemax="999999999999999" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"><span class="k-select">
```

Comment: Please, can you explain the html code? There are 4 input tags, but the two above are equals the others. Also, there is no class with `invalid` class to compare with the first input

Comment: What is the html code for the element you are finding for inputFirst? Based on your html code you have inserted in your question now, your `By inputTwoSrc` would find both the first and the third input elements, which might be causing you this headache.

Comment: Now I see. They are the same. Should I use xpath? To catch secound element after change of first one?

Comment: Yes, you can use `[n]` xpath helper, where n is the element number of a list of result that you want to obtain. Also, you can do the same with `nth-child(n)` from CssSelector, but it also depends how the html is renderized.